# Safely running code in a process, redirect stdout in multithreading.Process

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, stdout

I'm working on a dataset from a MOOC.  I have a lot of python3 code snippets that I need to run and get the results from.  To do this I've written a python script that loops over each snippet.  For each snippet I:

1. Create new StringIO objects
2. Set `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` to my stringIO buffers
3. Execute the code snippet in a `threading.thread` object
4. Join the thread
5. Log the results in the stringIO buffers
6. Restore stdout and stderr

This works fine for "correct" code, but this has issues in other cases:

- When the code has an infinite loop, thread.join doesn't kill the thread.  The thread is a daemon thread, so it runs quietly in the background until my loop finishes.
- When the code has an infinite loop with a `print()`, the thread starts overwriting my actual stdout when I set it back to the default (away from the StringIO buffer).  This pollutes my reporting.

Here is my current code:

```
def execCode(code, testScript=None):
    # create file-like string to capture output
    codeOut = io.StringIO()
    codeErr = io.StringIO()

    # capture output and errors
    sys.stdout = codeOut
    sys.stderr = codeErr

    def worker():
        exec(code, globals())

        if testScript:
            # flush stdout/stderror
            sys.stdout.truncate(0)
            sys.stdout.seek(0)
            # sys.stderr.truncate(0)
            # sys.stderr.seek(0)
            exec(testScript)

    thread = threading.Thread(target=worker, daemon=True)
    # thread = Process(target=worker) #, stdout=codeOut, stderr=codeErr)
    thread.start()
    thread.join(0.5)  # 500ms

    execError = codeErr.getvalue().strip()
    execOutput = codeOut.getvalue().strip()

    if thread.is_alive():
        thread.terminate()
        execError = "TimeError: run time exceeded"

    codeOut.close()
    codeErr.close()

    # restore stdout and stderr
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__

    # restore any overridden functions
    restoreBuiltinFunctions()

    if execError:
        return False, stripOuterException(execError)
    else:
        return True, execOutput
```

To handle this case, I've been trying to use `multithreading.Process` and/or `contextlib.redirect_stdout` to run the code in a process (then I can call `process.terminate()`), but I'm not having any success capturing stdout/stderr.

So my question is:  How can I redirect or capture stdout/stderr from a process?  Alternatively, is there some other way I could go about trying to run and capture the output of arbitrary code?

(And yes, I know this is a bad idea in general; I'm running it in a virtual machine just in case there is malicious code in there somewhere)

Python version is 3.5.3

---

## Update

It occurs to me that there is a little more flexibility in this situation.  I have a function, `preprocess(code)` that accepts a the code submission as a string and alters it.  Mostly I've been using it to swap out the value of some variables using regular expressions.

Here is an example implementation:

```
def preprocess(code):
    import re
    rx = re.compile('earlier_date\s*=\s*.+')
    code = re.sub(rx, "earlier_date = date(2016, 5, 3)", code)
    rx = re.compile('later_date\s*=\s*.+')
    code = re.sub(rx, "later_date = date(2016, 5, 24)", code)
    return code
```

I could use the preprocess function to help redirect STDOUT

Comment: Have you considered `logging`?

Comment: I have some logging.  My current work around is to turn on logging when I encounter an infinite loop.  I use the logging to track down and delete the offending snippet, but this is a manual process that can't really be automated (If I could automate it, I wouldn't need to log anything, I could just abort, delete the record, and continue)

Comment: What about [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)? You could call `python -c {snippet}` with it, or if it is longer, just write the snippet to a temporary `.py` file. `check_output` (and indeed, all the other functions in `subprocess`) has a `timeout` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Communicating with running process is not straightforward in Python. For some reason you can only do it once in subprocess life cycle. From my experience, it is best to run a thread that starts a process and after timeout gets its output and terminates the subprocess.

Something like:

```
def subprocess_with_timeout(cmd, timeout_sec, stdin_data=None):
    """Execute `cmd` in a subprocess and enforce timeout `timeout_sec` seconds.

    Send `stdin_data` to the subprocess.

    Return subprocess exit code and outputs on natural completion of the subprocess.
    Raise an exception if timeout expires before subprocess completes."""
    proc = os.subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    timer = threading.Timer(timeout_sec, proc.kill)
    # this will terminate subprocess after timeout
    timer.start()

    # you will be blocked here until process terminates (by itself or by timeout death switch)
    stdoutdata, stderrdata = proc.communicate(stdin_data) 

    if timer.is_alive():
        # Process completed naturally - cancel timer and return exit code
        timer.cancel()
        return proc.returncode, stdoutdata, stderrdata
    # Process killed by timer - raise exception
    raise TimeoutError('Process #%d killed after %f seconds' % (proc.pid, timeout_sec))
```

So, run a threaded executioner that calls for `subprocess_with_timeout`. It should handle the inputs and save the results.

Another idea is using a webserver to do the IPC. See [this link](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2017/interacting-with-a-long-running-child-process-in-python/)

Answer (score 0):

What about [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)? You could call `python -c {snippet}` with it, or if it is longer, just write the snippet to a temporary `.py` file. `check_output` (and indeed, all the other functions in `subprocess`) has a `timeout` parameter.

The general idea is then:

```
import subprocess
import sys

def execCode(code):
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, '-c', code],
                                         stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                         timeout=0.5)
        return True, output
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as te:
        return False, 'run time exceeded'
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as cpe:
        return False, cpe.stderr
```

Example runs in IPython:

```
In [18]: execCode('import os\nprint(" ".join(os.listdir()))')
Out[18]:
(True,
 b'contents of directory\n')

In [19]: execCode('import time\ntime.sleep(1)')
Out[19]: (False, 'run time exceeded')

In [20]: execCode('import os\nprint("\t".join(os.listdi))')
Out[20]: 
(False,
 b'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>\nAttributeError: module \'os\' has no attribute \'listdi\'\n')
```

Note that `check_output` returns a `bytes` sequence, so you will have to convert it into `str`. Or you can use the `encoding` parameter of `check_output`.